# Choosing which form field to submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `CommercialDocument` model which have a `discount_amount` attribute and a `discount_amount_with_tax` virtual attribute.

Here is how I defined this in my model :

```
def discount_amount_with_tax
  discount_amount * (1 + tax.rate / 100)
end

def discount_amount_with_tax=(amount)
  self.discount_amount = amount.to_f / (1 + tax.rate / 100)
end
```

In my form, a user can fill in both `discount_amount` and `discount_amount_tax` :

```
= f.label :discount_amount
= f.text_field :discount_amount
= f.text_field :discount_amount_with_tax
```

I want to give the priority to the `discount_amount_with_tax` field, which means that `discount_amount` must not be taken into account unless the other field is empty.

My problem is that if I put nothing in the `discount_amount_with_tax` field, and let's say 10 in `discount_amount`, then `discount_amount` will be equal to 0, which is clearly not what I want.

How can I fix this ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"".to_i
# => 0
```

A blank string converts to a *zero* integer. Therefore:

```
def discount_amount_with_tax=(amount)
  self.discount_amount = amount.to_f / (1 + tax.rate / 100)
end

# same as...

def discount_amount_with_tax=(0)
  self.discount_amount = 0 / (...)
end

# 0 / anything except zero = 0
# self.discount_amount = 0 no matter what
```

During mass-assignment, `discount_amount_with_tax=` is called. A blank form input is passed as an empty string, which Active Record then converts to an integer (zero). `discount_amount_with_tax=` sets `discount_amount` to zero regardless of `discount_amount`'s previous value.

Easy way around this is to use a conditional:

```
def discount_amount_with_tax=(amount)
  self.discount_amount = (amount.to_f / (1 + tax.rate / 100)) if amount > 0
end
```

Mind you, this is *the easy way*, not the ideal way. A better solution is to write custom setter logic in the controller in lieu of mass-assignment; basically to *manually* set these attributes in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a before_validation callback here to set the discount_amount field.

```
  before_validation :calculate_discount_amount

  def discount_amount_with_tax
    @discount_amount_with_tax ||= discount_amount * (1 + tax.rate / 100.0)
  end

  def discount_amount_with_tax=(amt)
    @discount_amount_with_tax = amt
  end

  def calculate_discount_amount
    self.discount_amount = discount_amount_with_tax / (1 + tax.rate / 100.0)
  end
```

Just a reminder that you need to use 100.0 instead of 100 so that you'll be dividing by float and not by integer.